# Using boto3 to update multiple resources with different values in single lambda script

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3

I want to iterate over all the resources in my account and update them based on an excel file which has some values that need to be updated. The problem I'm running into with my current code is it will only update the final value that is returned and not the others. How do i get it to update all resources?

```
import boto3

s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
client = boto3.client('resourcegroupstaggingapi')

def get_resource_tag(resource_name):
#this is an example, will have unique values returned from here. 
     return ['uniqueexample','value']

def update_resources_dict(resource):
    resource_name = resource["ResourceARN"]
    tag_to_update = get_resource_tag(resource_name)
    resource_list = [resource_name]
    return client.tag_resources(ResourceARNList =resource_list , Tags = {tag_to_update[0]:tag_to_update[1] })

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    all_resources=client.get_resources(ResourcesPerPage = 100)
    for resource in all_resources["ResourceTagMappingList"]:
        update_resources_dict(resource)
```

This function does not update each of the reosurces I use client.tag_resources on. How would i fix that?

Comment: When the code encounters a `return` statement, the Lambda function will exit. Instead, you could add values to a dictionary and then, at the very end of the `lambda_handler()` you could return the contents of the dictionary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Needed to append it to a something and return that. The following code solved it:

````
import boto3

s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
client = boto3.client('resourcegroupstaggingapi')

def get_resource_tag(resource_name):
     return ['uniqueexample','value']

def update_resources_dict(resource):
    resource_name = resource["ResourceARN"]
    tag_to_update = get_resource_tag(resource_name)
    resource_list = [resource_name]
    return client.tag_resources(ResourceARNList =resource_list , Tags = {tag_to_update[0]:tag_to_update[1] })

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    all_resources=client.get_resources(ResourcesPerPage = 100)
    rd = {}
    for resource in all_resources["ResourceTagMappingList"]:
        print(resource)
        rd[resource['ResourceARN']] = update_resources_dict(resource)
    return rd
    
       ```
````